# Compute $Var X$ using value of $Var X_i$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ will be independent random variables such that all of them  has the same distribution. Let $Var X_i = a$ for $i=1,..,n$.  Compute $Var X$ where $X=\frac1n (X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n)$.

So my approach is:
$$Var X = Var(1/nX_1+...+1/nX_n) = 1/n^2Var X_1+...+1/n^2 VarX_n = \frac{1}{n^2}na = \frac{a}{n}$$Am I ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general you have 
$$
\text{Var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var } X_i + 2\sum_{1 \le j<k \le n} \text{Cov} (X_j,X_k)
$$
and since the $X_i$ are independent, Cov($X_j,X_k) = 0$ whenever $j \neq k$, so this simplifies to 
$$
\text{Var} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var} X_i
$$

And of course, you use the above result in combination with Var $(cX) = c^2 \text{Var } X$ to get your result.